# How to know if MAC address is attached to wireless card or ethernet card?

Tags: python, monitoring, wireless, ethernet, mac-address

I'm performing network monitoring with a software developed by my company.
For each machine, I have the mac address of the card used to connect to the network.

I'm looking for a way to know, from the MAC address (for example), if the card is an Ethernet card or a wireless card.

I can use nmap and openvas sensors results in my analysis.

The final goal is to get a hint to know if the machine is a workstation or a laptop.

I'm programming in python, but any other solution is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: There are certainly better ways to try and figure out this information. For example, how do you have the MAC address?

Comment: You can use the first 6 digits to find the vendor. Maybe that'll help. Try [**this**](http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/). However, it is not possible to tell if it is a laptop or not from the MAC.

Comment: In fact I use nmap and openvas scan result, if MAC doesn't help maybe another part of these report can be usefull

Comment: What operating system? On Windows you can use WMI. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40088578/1498252 for detecting connector presence.

Answer (score 1):

This is the canonical list of NIC vendors: http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt

You could use this list to get the vendor from a MAC address, then make some educated guesses. For example, Atmel makes mostly Wireless NICs.

Comment: +1 Might be good to mention it isn't reliable, as MACs were not meant to tell Ethernet and Wireless cards, or Workstations and Laptops apart.

Comment: thanks for the idea but many times I find Intel, apple, sony and so one... so it's not really helpful.
I know MAC isn't design to give this information, but if you have another way, I have nmap and openvas sensors results that I can use