# Python: is a given network interface wifi or ethernet?

Tags: python, wifi, ethernet, network-interface

Is there a way, from within **Python**, to know if a given (and connected) **network interface** is **wifi** or **Ethernet**?

The module [`inetfaces`](http://alastairs-place.net/projects/netifaces/) provides a list of network interfaces available and corresponding addresses, but nothing more.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648941/how-to-know-if-mac-address-is-attached-to-wireless-card-or-ethernet-card

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281341/get-local-network-interface-addresses-using-only-proc

Comment: Actually, I would run in a separate process `iwconfig $interfaceName` and parse the result. Would this be ok?

Answer (score 2):

With [pyroute2](https://github.com/svinota/pyroute2).IW (a script like that is in the examples directory):

```
import sys
from pyroute2 import IW
from pyroute2 import IPRoute
from pyroute2.netlink import NetlinkError

ip = IPRoute()
iw = IW()
index = ip.link_lookup(ifname=sys.argv[1])[0]
try:
    iw.get_interface_by_ifindex(index)
    print("wireless interface")
except NetlinkError as e:
    if e.code == 19:  # 19 'No such device'
        print("not a wireless interface")
finally:
    iw.close()
    ip.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python **scapy** module.

```
from scapy.all import *
print(get_windows_if_list())
```