# Which addresses are for the network?

Tags: c#, tcp, ip

I'm calling code like this, and it gives good info:

```
    string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
    IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
```

Here's the data:

> - ```
>   [0] {fe80::d2f:b4c7:e592:9612%18}   System.Net.IPAddress        AddressFamily       InterNetworkV6  System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily
>   IsIPv4MappedToIPv6  false   bool        IsIPv6LinkLocal     true    bool
>   IsIPv6Multicast     false   bool        IsIPv6SiteLocal     false   bool
>   IsIPv6Teredo        false   bool        ScopeId 18      long
>   ```
> - ```
>   [1] {fe80::1ef:a74b:40eb:79f2%19}   System.Net.IPAddress        AddressFamily       InterNetworkV6  System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily
>   IsIPv4MappedToIPv6  false   bool        IsIPv6LinkLocal     true    bool
>   IsIPv6Multicast     false   bool        IsIPv6SiteLocal     false   bool
>   IsIPv6Teredo        false   bool        ScopeId 19      long
>   ```
> - ```
>   [2] {172.31.14.146} System.Net.IPAddress        Address 2450399148  long        AddressFamily       InterNetwork    System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily
>   IsIPv4MappedToIPv6  false   bool        IsIPv6LinkLocal     false   bool
>   IsIPv6Multicast     false   bool        IsIPv6SiteLocal     false   bool
>   IsIPv6Teredo        false   bool
>   ```
> - ```
>   [3] {172.28.255.138}    System.Net.IPAddress        Address 2331974828  long        AddressFamily       InterNetwork    System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily
>   IsIPv4MappedToIPv6  false   bool        IsIPv6LinkLocal     false   bool
>   IsIPv6Multicast     false   bool        IsIPv6SiteLocal     false   bool
>   IsIPv6Teredo        false   bool
>   ```

But there's no indication on the IPHostEntry of where the adapter connects. Here's the IP config from CMD:

> ```
> C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig
>
> Windows IP Configuration
>
> Ethernet adapter Ethernet 12:
>
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : inside.1-stop.biz
>    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d2f:b4c7:e592:9612%18
>    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.31.14.146
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.31.14.254
>
> Unknown adapter OpenVPN TAP-Windows6:
>
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1ef:a74b:40eb:79f2%19
>    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.28.255.138
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
> ```

I don't want the VPN one...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089685/c-sharp-finding-my-machines-local-ip-address-and-not-the-vms

Comment: Thanks Martheen! So fast, and so correct haha