# Programmatically determine whether a network card is integrated or discrete on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, networking, uniqueidentifier, mac-address

I know I can use `GetAdaptersAddresses` to retrieve information for the network interfaces on a machine. Additionally, I would like to determine which of those interfaces refer to network cards integrated on the motherboard. The requirement is similar to that discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3530362/2833126/. The accepted answer there is to check whether the card is a PCI device. I don't think this will work because I believe integrated cards are reported as PCI devices (I can't actually test this right now as I don't have access to a Windows machine right now... at least they show up in the `lspci` output on Linux).

The use case for this is similar to that mentioned in the SO post linked above: to generate a unique system ID based on the MAC address. I would like to use the MAC address of an integrated card since it is attached to the motherboard and for my problem I would like the system ID to correspond to the motherboard.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was a general and reliable method for differentiating between integrated and discrete.

Comment: Well, it doesn't necessarily need to reliable since using MAC addresses at all is error prone. Something like 90% is probably good enough. Generality is a requirement, though. This is for a non-critical feature, so I don't want to write hundreds of lines of vendor-specific special cases.

Comment: Just make sure you handle the case where there is no on-board adapter!

Answer (score 1):

check [Win32_OnBoardDevice class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394238(v=vs.85).aspx)
in powershell you can do:

```
PS C:\temp> gwmi Win32_OnBoardDevice|?{$_.devicetype -eq 5} |select -expand description
Broadcom 5754 NetXtreme Gigabit Controller
```

Comment: This looks promising. Do you know whether any of the Win32_OnBoardDevice fields can be matched against fields in [IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? It looks like `Name` and `AdapterName` might be the only possibility.

Comment: hum... not easy, i thought description would have match with Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration but it's not the case ...